# Getting an error while updating docker services

Tags: docker

I am trying to update docker service but I get this error

> "update paused due to failure or early termination of task lhsarfbg2obvmxbbpygsysg7a"

I also run `sudo docker service ps 'service-name'` but tasks are running and shutdown within minutes

Any ideas on how I can resolve this?

Comment: Hi, you can look your docker daemon log to see more.
And do you use docker stack for your deployment ? If you use it, the attribute depends_on can generate this kind of error.

Comment: I am using docker stack for deployment, but don't think that depends_on attribute is generating this kind of error.
Results from docker daemon log "-- Logs begin at Fri 2019-01-04 11:44:47 CET. --
 level=error msg="fatal task error" error="task: non-zero exit (2)" module=node/agent/taskmanager 
" level=error msg="Not continuing with pull after error: errors:\ndenied: requested access to the resource is denied\nunauthorized: authentication required\n"

Comment: ok, you can try to scale to 0 your service and check if any containers still running. And retry your update.

Comment: The same problem. I tried to re-install project from beginning, after running commands to start stack, all services are created but one of containers is exiting and creating within seconds. The command 'docker service ls' shows replicas 0/1 for one of the services. Also 'docker service ps #id_services' shows that task is changing state within seconds.

Comment: can you pull your image manually ?